# Selenium-IDE: using qooxdoo user-extension locators with the UI-Element mapping feature

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, selenium-ide, qooxdoo

I would like to know how (if anyone has made it work) to use the qooxdoo element locators provided by the `user-extension.js` file for Selenium-IDE from within UI-Element mapping files.

The UI-Element mapping file would contain entries like:

```
map.addElement('page', {
  name: 'accept-button',
  description: '...',
  locator: 'qxh=child[4]/qx.ui.core.scroll.ScrollPane/qx.ui.container.Composite/child[1]'
});
```

and then a locator in a Selenium test case could be:

```
qxClick ui=page::accept-button()
```

I have successfully matched UI-Elements in this way when they are defined with a standard Selenium locator but using the qooxdoo extension locators (`qxh`, `qxhv` etc.) just doesn't seem to work.

After going round in circles attempting to debug the JavaScript inside the Selenium-IDE Firefox add-on it is apparent that there is something odd about the execution context during the attempt to resolve the `ui=...` Selenium locators when the target is defined using a qooxdoo locator as above.

I am not very familiar with the Firefox add-on development process and it seems these are notoriously difficult to debug, even the `LOG` methods are affected by the execution context oddity I mentioned such that no output is produced from within the methods involved when resolving the qooxdoo locators which makes the process even harder to follow.

I'm going to continue looking at this for a while but any help would be appreciated.

I am currently using **Selenium-IDE 1.3.0** add-on inside **Firefox 7.0.1** and **qooxdoo 1.3.1** for the *application under test*.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run only with Selenium IDE. You have to use the Simulator component of Qooxdoo and write test cases in javascript using Qooxdoo API and Selenium API.

Use Qooxdoo1.4 or above (current version is 1.6), Qooxdoo team have integrated the Inspector and Simulator components into the SDK itself. You don't have to setup those components separately as in qooxdoo1.3.
I and my friend wrote a beginner's guide for qooxdoo. It contains a separate chapter for Testing and Debugging.

The book details can be found at http://link.packtpub.com/sQxPXC
There is some introductory offer as the book is just launched!

~raffi

Comment: raffimd, you're right in that Selenium IDE isn't the right tool to run tests, however the question is about developing and debugging Selenium extensions, a task for which it's very useful.

Comment: Daniel, It is tricky to get the reliable location strategy for the widgets as the GUI is generated dynamically. We used the Selenium-IDE, qooxdoo Inspector together with the knowledge of various location strategies to come up with a reliable location strategy, so that the test script runs always and We are writing the test cases in the javascript as the qooxdoo supports it through simulator component.

Answer (score 0):

False, you can use Selenium IDE by itself :

http://simplapi.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/qooxdoo-and-selenium-ide-alternate-testing-system/

Comment: Forgot to say, Selenium IDE is great to write fast test, and export them into a selenium RC for exampe, so it help a lot to go faster.

Comment: You should add a disclaimer that this is your own website